# Dynamic SVG image with Laravel 5.4 PHP - SQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, svg

I have 26 classrooms, my idea is that on a school floor plan, fill a classroom with a color in the SVG image when it is in use.

Already did, but I think I have to do 26 query sql, one for each classroom.
Is it correct or can there be another way?

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $dataClassr  = Classroom::all()->where('name_classroom', 'sistemas 1')->first();

    return view('welcome')->with('dataClassr', $dataClassr);
}
```

View:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 545 532.5">
    <title>Recurso 3</title>
    <g>
        <polyline points="315 484 264 483.5 264 268.5 213 268.5 213 84.5 200 84.5 200 0.5 265 0.5 265 172.5 315 172.5" style="fill: #cecece;stroke: #000;stroke-miterlimit: 10"/>
        <g>
            // Conditional
            @if($dataClassr->availability == 'not available')
              <rect x="1" y="83.5" width="221" height="177" style="fill: #fc7;stroke: #111;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 2px"/>
            @endif

            <rect x="265" y="4.5" width="219" height="168" style="fill: #fff;stroke: #111;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 2px"/>
            <rect x="315" y="172.5" width="229" height="359" style="fill: #fff;stroke: #111;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 2px"/>
            <text transform="translate(52.96 176.84)" style="font-size: 23.11184310913086px;font-family: MyriadPro-Regular, Myriad Pro">Class<tspan x="48.3" y="0" style="letter-spacing: -0.009993016574206285em">r</tspan><tspan x="55.63" y="0">oom 1</tspan></text>
            <text transform="translate(314.96 95.84)" style="font-size: 23.11184310913086px;font-family: MyriadPro-Regular, Myriad Pro">Class<tspan x="48.3" y="0" style="letter-spacing: -0.009993016574206285em">r</tspan><tspan x="55.63" y="0">oom 2</tspan></text>
            <text transform="translate(374.96 365.84)" style="font-size: 23.11184310913086px;font-family: MyriadPro-Regular, Myriad Pro">Class<tspan x="48.3" y="0" style="letter-spacing: -0.009993016574206285em">r</tspan><tspan x="55.63" y="0">oom 3</tspan></text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

With a foreach, print many elements rect

The result is
[image]

Comment: without knowing your DB set up etc. So your classrom name column is `name_classroom` ? coudl you not simply call all where the value is say true.  Classroom::all()->where('FIELD_NAME', 'sistemas 1'true)->get();  This should then get all those that are ture then simply iterate over them

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try as my comment try changing the `first()` to `get()`:

`Classroom::all()->where('name_classroom', 'sistemas 1')->get();`

As the first as it states gets the first result, if youwant them all use the get() option.

Answer (score -1):

Try and run a foreach statement on your view to echo out each and every svg in the $dataClassr array.